# How do I insert text in first table row with Javascript in Limesurvey

Tags: javascript, html, limesurvey

I am required to insert text inside the first leftmost row of a table, which comes in a Matrix question type in Limesurvey.

This is not originally possible right from the admin panel. I have figured out to insert javascript code.

Inspecting the table, unfortunately, that first row doesn't have neither a class nor an id to select it directly.

This is how I have managed to get that first `<td>` inside the `<thead>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("test");
        //Seleccionar la tabla correspondiente
        var t = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="ls-question-text-852216X2X7"]');
      d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0],
      r = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      var td = $(t).find("thead td").eq(0).children().first();
      console.log(td);
      //td.innerHTML = "mytext";
    });
</script>
```

However, I don't know how to insert the text inside that cell. I have tried the `innerHTML()` function but it's not working.

The result of `console.log(td)` is the following object:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }
​
length: 0
​
prevObject: Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }
​​
length: 0
​​
prevObject: Object { 0: td
, length: 1, prevObject: {…} }
​​​
0: <td class="">
​​​
length: 1
​​​
prevObject: Object { 0: td, length: 1, prevObject: {…} }
```

From that object, I see the element of interest: `0: <td class="">`, then how do I do to insert the desired text just there?

- What am I missing?
- How do I insert that text?

## **Solved**

Thanks to @wazz I could solve it.

So I select the table:

```
var t = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="ls-question-text-852216X2X7"]');
```

and then I finally insert the text:

```
t.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "text";
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a cell?

Comment: @wazz yeah, but I got a huge object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if there's an ID on your table (`var t` I think.) If there is, it *should* be straightforward. Does this work?

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "text";
```

That gets the first cell of the first row. If there's a table-header, it will get the first cell of the header (header is included), so adjust the row as needed.

Comment: In this case, the table does not have any `id`. The only way I can select it is through the `var t = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="ls-question-text-852216X2X7"]');` attribute. So based on your answer I adapted it to: `var t = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="ls-question-text-852216X2X7"]');` and then `t.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "text";`

Comment: Right, as I thought. So you have the table, does the code above work? You would use `t.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML`. Edit: just beat me to the edit. Good!